# connecting already existing database in a local environment

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, migration, mysql-workbench

I have an access database that connects to a vb6 application and this whole thing is connected between two computers via a shared network one running win 8 and other a win 7, and there is no internet involved in any sorta way nor should it be that is a requirement in fact

sorry I advance I have tried researching on the net but there is really short time and a lot of confusing material online

I am creating a WPF app connected to MySQL DB

now I have copied the access file and imported the contents of the DB in MySQL
things are a real mess in the imported DB so I am fixing it

what I am confused is how I am going to make it work there

- do I go and install MySQL and do the whole process manually there, repeating all the steps and changes
  is made
- make a document that contains the code/script for all the changes I have made and run the data through
  it, and is there even a way to implement that as a whole in a singular go
- connect both databases together, i don't even know if this is possible

Answer (score 2):

yes, in place of a simple "file share" of the Access file, you now are going to run some kind of SQL server system. In this case MySQL. But it could be PostgreSQL or any kind of "server" database.

That instance of "sql server" thus has to be setup, installed and you ensure that the "box" running that instance of MySQL also allows external connections (often by default the given computer firewall settings prevent this).

At that point, 2 or 10 different computers on that same network can now simply connect to the SQL server. The code of course is going to be VERY simular. You almost for sure used the oleDB provider for use with Access. However, you can use the ODBC provider, or even use the provider from MySQL. Those providers thus means you change the connect object, datareader object etc. However the "base" .net types such as row, or datatable, or dataset can remain as before (so you only change the provider). If you have a lot of code based on oleDB, then you could well consider to contine to use that oleDB provider code in .net, and thus you change the connection strings to now point to MySQL.

If you don't have a lot of code, then for sure do adopt the mySQL provider for .net. But as noted the least amount of changes would be to continue to use a oleDB provider for mysql, and that would suggest the least amount of code to be changed.

As for the msaccess data migration? Well, it not clear what tools and how you doing that now. But, once you transfer the data to the MySQL server (assuming you installed + setup my sql to run on one computer). The it is a simple matter to point your .net connection(s) in your code to Now MySQL as opposed to Acess. As a result, most if not all of your code logic for working with the tables can remain as before - but as noted you have to swap out the provider parts in .net

Now, if your REALLY lucky and the .net code used the ODBC provider? Then all you have to do is change your connection strings. And of course "some" SQL syntax in your code may have to be tweaked, as like Oracle, MS SQL server, postgreSQL, and MySQL?

Well, they all have some features and syntax that is different - this is especially in regards to date/time calculations, datediff() etc. But the general sql you have/had in your .net code should continue to run mostly un-changed against MySQL data tables.

As for how to migrate the data? I think that a really good tool is of course to use MS-Access. What you do is get MySQL up and running. Then use ms-access to open that database. You then add linked tables from MS-access to the MySQL tables.

At that point, you can now run append queries from Access to move/send the data to MySQL. It really depends on how many tables, and how many related tables are in that database. The more complex and the greater number of related tables in Access then the more the challenge to move such data up to MySQL.

Transferring Excel or a small or even big table is a breeze. (again, use MS Access and link to the tables on the sql server). However, where things can become messy is that if you have say 25 tables, and they are all related, many have cascade delete and say enforced parent to child relationships. So the more tables, and especially a larger number of related data tables, then the more work such a data migration task will become.

I think MS Access is a really good tool, since if you setup a connection to MySQL, then you can execute a transferDatabase commend in Access to send up one table to MySQL, and even all the columns and data types for those columns will be automatic created for you. So not only can Access transfer the data, but MORE valuable is it has the abilty to create the target tables on MySQL for you - and that will save you large amounts of time to build + setup the tables on MySQL.